# How do you design an interface with a list of varying width elements?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder

I want the interface to look something like the right side of the Things interface but the items in the list need to be of different widths. Is this achievable with the Interface Builder or do I have to use drawing? I'd like as detailed an explanation as possible. Thanks!

Like this

[image: Things]
<sub>(source: [culturedcode.com](https://culturedcode.com/styles_2.5/images/screenshot_things_big5.jpg))</sub>
:

Comment: The title says height but your question mentions widths – I assume height is the intended meaning?

Comment: Oops, you're right - it should say width. I can't edit it now because I'll lose the image. Do edit if you can.

Comment: I've edited the question to say "width" instead of "height".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Steve Degutis's code over on [SDListView](http://github.com/sdegutis/SDListView) on GitHub.

This is a subclass of NSCollectionView for a single column with variable height items.

I know it's only a link, but its as detailed an answer as the question.

Answer (score 0):

NSTableView allows for varying-height rows using the [tableView:heightOfRow:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:heightOfRow:) delegate method.